# How do I properly scope functions with CoffeeScript in browser?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, scope

```
(->
  jQuery ->
    globalThis = @
    $('#emailTypes').change ->
      globalThis.toggleEmailOptions()

  toggleEmailOptions = ->
    $('.emailTypeOptions').fadeOut 'fast', ->
      for emailType in $('#emailTypes').val()
        $("##{emailType}Options").fadeIn()


).call this
```

That's my `.coffee` file. However, the `toggleEmailOptions` function isn't in scope of the jQuery `ready`. How can I make it in scope?

Comment: since toggleEmailOptions is a local variable anyway, you can just move it inside the jQuery.Ready callback. If you want to make toggleEmailOptions available on the global scope, you can use => in place of -> to keep the this inside functions and declare @toggleEmailOptions in place of toggleEmailOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to wrap because coffeescript already do it, here's how I would rewrite your code:

```
jQuery ->
  toggleEmailOptions = ->
    $('.emailTypeOptions').fadeOut 'fast', ->
      for emailType in $('#emailTypes').val()
        $("##{emailType}Options").fadeIn()

  $('#emailTypes').change ->
    toggleEmailOptions()
```

Comment: This is good, but that means I always have to define functions before I use them. I'd rather not do that because I want to organize my code a particular way.

Comment: actually you don't have to declare it first, it was just easier to read imho, copy paste on http://js2coffee.org/ you'll see the toggleEmailOptions variable is declared at the beginning of the callback in all cases ;)

Answer (score 2):

From http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

> The usual caveats about CoffeeScript apply — your inline scripts will
>   run within a closure     wrapper, so if you want to expose global
>   variables or functions, attach them to the window object.

Or bind to `exports` if you're using node.js .

For your example, it becomes:

```
window.toggleEmailOptions = ->
```

Comment: '    $('#emailTypes').change ->
      window.toggleEmailOptions()
' doesn't appear to work =(

Comment: Try without the parens at the end. You are binding to the result value of calling the function, not the function itself.

Comment: What if I want to do file-wide scope? I don't want it to be bound to the window.. just "global" within this particular file?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think window == this for your "file scope", which is set up by default. Have a look at http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2009/10/es5-and-function-default-scope.html

Comment: @Marius, you're right @/this == window by default in coffeescript in browser context

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here. One is that you seems to be assuming that `@`/`this` is the global object (`window`) from the jQuery callback. But it's easy to see that it isn't:

```
jQuery -> console.log @ is window  # false
```

Remember that callbacks can be called in whatever context the library wants. In this case, `@` is `document`. And `document.toggleEmailOptions` doesn't exist.

Further, if you want `toggleEmailOptions` to be a global, you need to attach it to `window` (or `@`/`this`, since `@ is window` in the outermost scope of your file). That's because when you just write `toggleEmailOptions = ...`, CoffeeScript scopes it within the file using a `var` declaration. It's easy to see this by looking at the compiled JS: `var`s are always at the top of their scope. Fortunately, file scope is what you wanted anyway.

So basically: Don't overthink it! What you want is:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#emailTypes').change ->
    toggleEmailOptions()
```

and leave the rest as it is.